# R assign value of a column base on other column's condition

Tags: r, reverse-geocoding

I want to apply reverse_geo function if the address is empty and latitude and longitude are not empty.
The csv file:

| latitude | longitude | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 38.89770 | -77.03655 | Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, District of columbia, 20045, United States |
| 37.79520 | -122.40279 |  |
| 41.87535 |  |  |

The code I run is:

```
library(tidygeocoder)
library(dplyr)

path <- "mypath"
data <- read.csv (paste (path, "sample2.csv", sep = ""))
data
data<-data %>%
  mutate(address = case_when(address=="" & latitude!="" & longitude!="" ~ reverse_geo(lat = latitude, long = longitude, method = "osm")))
```

But I got

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `address = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error:
! Can't use NA as column index with `[` at positions 1, 2, and 3.
```

Which I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do that:

```
data$address <- ifelse((is.na(data$address) | data$address == '') & !(is.na(data$latitude) | is.na(data$longitude)), 
              reverse_geo(lat = data$latitude, 
                          long = data$longitude, method = "osm")$address,
              data$address)
```

or better that:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)
query_df <- data[(is.na(data$address) | data$address == '') & !(is.na(data$latitude) | is.na(data$longitude)),]
query_df$address <- reverse_geo(lat = query_df$latitude, 
                                long = query_df$longitude, method = "osm")$address

data <- merge(data, query_df[!is.na(address),], by = c("latitude", "longitude"), all = TRUE)
data$address <- ifelse(is.na(data$address.y), data$address.x, data$address.y)
data$address.x <- NULL
data$address.y <- NULL
```

because first suggestion is going to load the server with useless queries.

Comment: Although the logic you are using is check latitude and longitude is NA first, but it works!

Comment: yes, if im missing the latitude or the longitude, then i use the address, otherwise i query the loc. I've just edited the code to also take into account when an address is provided but i'm sure you follow me...

Comment: When I saw your code at a glance, I thought you misunderstood me, but I tried the code anyway and surprisly worked. And I looked the code several times finally got what you mean. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Also if you're happy with the solution please accept the answer...

Comment: Oh, I thought I just need to upvote it. Sorry.